Oracle SQL difference in days between two dates with different formats - SYSDATE and a VARCHAR2
I am trying to find the difference in days between a VARCHAR2 value (context sensitive) in format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS and SYSDATE.
If I use in select
TO_DATE(peevf.screen_entry_value,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TRUNC(SYSDATE)
I get 80 which is what I expect, but if I try to use as a condition where
TO_DATE(peevf.screen_entry_value,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = TRUNC(SYSDATE + 80)

I get an error
ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format.

Any ideas?
(the column I am looking at is pay_element_entry_values_f.screen_entry_value)

OK got the answer for those interested.
SUBSTR(SYSDATE+80,1,10) = SUBSTR(peevf4.screen_entry_value,1,10)
